# How do i get the windowid for a window from my application?

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I try to run "screecncapture" terminal command from my app , but ai receive an error and i'm not really sure why.

Here is my code :

```
 system("screencapture -l\(nameOfMyWindow.identifier) page.png")
```

an the error that i receive is that :

> No images found for wid 1 screencapture could not capture window 1

nameOfMyWindow.identifier should be the windowId. Is another method to receive this windowId ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you need to run `screencapture`? Why can't you use the `CGWindowList` API, such as `CGWindowListCreateImage()`? Or what about `-[NSWindow dataWithPDFInsideRect:]`?

Comment: Thanks ! [NSWindow dataWithPDFInsideRact:] is exactly what i need !